# I got Ethernet bridging to work but I am puzzled by the Icon that is presented in the windows 10 networking status area

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, ethernet, bridge

I was having a lot of trouble getting the Ethernet bridging to work on my home network. The network is in my shop area downstairs and connects with my router upstairs by Wi-Fi. The bandwidth on the router is maxed at 600mb/s, but I get up to 550 in my shop on any single computer. But I wanted to have the 3 computers share the Wi-Fi network on one of the computers through an external TP-Link unmanaged Gigabit Ethernet switch. I followed the steps suggested by DoubleD on September 25, 2020:(see steps below):

It didn't work right away but it came up after a reboot. So all three computers can now use the high speed Ethernet link on the computer that I put the bridge on. What I am asking is the icon on the bridging computer shows a serial link connection and I expected to see a Wi-Fi connection as that is how the bridge connects to the router upstairs. Why does it show a serial Ethernet link as connected?

> Wi-Fi CAN be bridged to Ethernet on Windows 10.
>
> 1.Connect to Internet via WiFi. Take note of your private IP settings (e.g. IP:192.168.1.44 SM:255.255.255.0 GW:192.168.1.1 DNS:192.168.1.1)
> 2. In Control Panel > Network and Internet > Network Connections, highlight WiFi and Ethernet (use shift click or Ctrl Click or shift
> arrow key). Rt-click on highlighted area and choose "Bridge
> Connections"
>
> 3.At this point, hosting PC will likely lose Internet especially if you connect a device on the Ethernet port.
>
> 4.To correct this loss of Internet on "host PC", go to Control Panel > Network and Internet > Network Connections, and double-click "Network
> Bridge" to open Network Bridge Status dialogue.
> 5.Click Properties button (might be slow to populate, be patient) Highlight WiFi in top box
>
> 6.Double-click IPv4 in bottom box to open IPv4 Properties Select "Use the following IP address" and manually fill in settings recorded from
> step TWO. OK your way out
>
> 7.Enjoy Internet on both your "host PC" as well as add-on device connected to host PC via Ethernet (extension of your WiFi network).
> Note1: This also works with LAN-LAN bridge
>
> 8. Double-click IPv4 in bottom box to open IPv4 Properties
>
> 9.Select "Use the following IP address" and manually fill in settings recorded from step TWO.
> 10. OK your way out Enjoy Internet on both your "host PC" as well as add-on device connected to host PC via Ethernet (extension of your
> WiFi network).

Note1: This also works with LAN-LAN bridge.

Note2: I disabled IPv6 on "wireless bridge" but probably unnecessary.

Comment: please add a picture of the icon to your post